# Displaying Foreign Key reference Value

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to display the foreign key reference values in the template. My Models are as below

```
class CustomerType(models.Model):

    customer_type_id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_type_name      = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Prospects(models.Model):

    prospect_id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_type       = models.ForeignKey(CustomerType )
```

My Query

```
prospectList = Prospects.objects.using (settings.DATABASE_CONF).filter (status=1).values 
        ('prospect_id' , 'customer_type')
```

Template

```
<td>
{{ prospect.customer_type_id }}
</td>
```

Im able to get only 'customer_type_id' but I want to display 'customer_type_name'. How to do it. I tried '__' option but that doesnt work.

Comment: Does `{{ prospect.customer_type.queryset.customer_type_name }}` or `{{ prospect.customer_type.customer_type_name }}` work?

Comment: No both of them are not working.

Comment: I'm afraid that's might be because of `values`, could you omit it for testing purpose?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `values`, foreign keys are not followed. From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values):

> If you have a field called foo that is a ForeignKey, the default values() call will return a dictionary key called foo_id, since this is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value (the foo attribute refers to the related model). When you are calling values() and passing in field names, you can pass in either foo or foo_id and you will get back the same thing (the dictionary key will match the field name you passed in).

As @alecxe said, omit `.values` call.